# What means the weight in an igraph edge?

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to execute community detection algorithms in `igraph` on python, I am using as a weight of the edge the strength of the connection between them, but I don't know if the `igraph` algorithms use it as a distance metric or a strength metric.

Answer (score 0):

`igraph` as a whole has no such interpretation.  It's a package that supports a variety of operations on an abstract graph -- a bipartite set of nodes and edges, each of which have various properties.  The interpretation is driven by the use case.

The semantics of the edge weight depend on the application.  The appropriate metaphor depends on the [method called](https://igraph.org/python/doc/python-igraph.pdf).  For instance, `shortest_paths_dijkstra` treats them as distance or cost.  `evcent` sees them as connection strength.  `maxflow` uses them as flow capacity.